# Setting model value from nested JSON object

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I'm receiving a menu of products that are returned as a JSON string.  from that data I am trying to populate a list of product models and send to my view for display as a type of live menu.  my code used for retrieving the data is as follows; excluding the headers being sent as I am receiving everything correctly already;

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                List<MenuItem> Products = new List<MenuItem>();

                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
                JToken item = jsonObject["data"];

                foreach (var menuitem in item)
                {
                    MenuItem product = new MenuItem(menuitem);
                    Products.Add(product);                        
                }
```

my MenuItem model is receiving each individual item and trying to set the model values;

```
 public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(JToken product)
    {
        Id = (Int32)product["id"];
        Name = (string)product["name"];
        Item_Number = (string)product["item_number"];
        Description = (string)product["description"];           


        Pricing.Default_Price = (string)product["pricing"]["default_price"];
        Pricing.Pricing_Group_Id = (Int32)product["pricing"]["pricing_group_id"];

    }
```

There's a lot more substance to the model but this should be all that is needed

```
        public Pricing Pricing { get; set; }

}
public class Pricing
{
    public string Default_Price { get; set; }
    public Int32 Pricing_Group_Id { get; set; }
    public string Pricing_Group_Name { get; set; }
    public WeightPrices Weight_Prices { get; set; }
}
public class WeightPrices
{
    public Int32 Pricing_Weight_Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public float Default_Price { get; set; }
}
```

The issue that I am running into are on the lines trying to set the Pricing values from a deeper child element.

```
Pricing.Default_Price = (string)product["pricing"]["default_price"];
    Pricing.Pricing_Group_Id = (Int32)product["pricing"]["pricing_group_id"];
```

My code throws as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when it hits those lines.  When adding a watch in VS2017 the value is correct, but I still receive this error.  The format of the JSON string is;

```
{"data": [
{
"id": 2148487,
"name": "3.5 grams of Blue Dream",
"item_number": "8AEO00000001",
"description": "",
"pricing": {
  "default_price": "20.00",
  "pricing_group_id": 5908,
  "weight_prices": [
    {
      "pricing_weight_id": 21504,
      "default_price": "12.00",
      "name": ".5g",
      "uom": "GR",
      "weight": 0.5
    },
    {
      "pricing_weight_id": 21505,
      "default_price": "20.00",
      "name": "1g",
      "uom": "GR",
      "weight": 1
    }
  ],
  "pricing_group_name": "Top Shelf"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, i have yet to start on the weight prices, that's next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Pricing` property is never instantiated, so it is null whenever you try to set the value of a property on it.

Before you set the `Default_Price`, set `Pricing = new Pricing()`